# Best way to create a product table with the attributes, color, sizes and photos (like ecommerce)

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, relationship

I have a question, it is more related to good modeling practices.
I am making a system that will have categories HABTM products (shoes) and these products will have their attributes (color, sizes, product photos), however the size and photos of the product will be related to color. For example:
I have a black boot and in that color is available sizes: 24, 25 and 28 and the photos of the black boot.
I have a brown boot and in that color is available the sizes: 21, 23 and 24 and the photos of the brown boot.

I thought of the sizes and the photos being HABTM of color, but that would cause me a problem when I was doing the select of the products it would not bring the third level.

I use cakephp 2.x

Comment: Please be more clear as to exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Hello, how are you? What I want is to know the best way to create a table of products where there will be dependencies (shoe color table, sizes table and photo gallery), however depending on the color will have available different numbers and different photos.
I do not know if I create a table of products and another table with general attributes, or if I create a table products with habtm colors and this yes is the parent table of the photos tables and numbering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set up a HABTM relationship between colors and sizes.  You could create a join table that would look something like this:

```
id | color_id | size_id
```

You would then have a `colors` table and a `sizes` table.

I don't think you need a HABTM relationship between `colors` and `photos`.  I think you can just use a `hasMany` relationship because each photo is unique to a color.  Your `photos` table would just have a foreign key column pointing to the `colors` table.

```
id | color_id
```

Comment: Thank you bill! You opened my head. I will try to do so. I only have doubts about find this data in the database when searching for a product, because the sizes is related to the colors and not directly to the product.